# Ruby: mixins, inheritance and constants name resolution

Tags: ruby

My program has following structure:

```
module M1
    class A
        def action
            C.new.foo
        end
    end

    class C
        def foo
            puts "M1::C foo"
        end
    end
end


module M2
    class A
        def action
            C.new.foo
        end
    end

    class C
        def foo
            puts "M2::C foo"
        end
    end
end
```

As both `M1::A` and `M2::A` share same code, I've been thinking of putting common code inside separate class (or module) and inherit from it (include it). Something like this:

```
class ABase
    def action
        C.new.foo
    end
end

module M1
    class A < ABase
    end

    class C
        def foo
            puts "M1::C foo"
        end
    end
end


module M2
    class A < ABase
    end

    class C
        def foo
            puts "M2::C foo"
        end
    end
end
```

However, when I tried, I've got into trouble with name resolution `uninitialized constant ABase::C`. What is the proper way to achieve code sharing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way constants are resolved based on definition scope and not in inherited scopes you'll need to bridge that with a method call:

```
class ABase
  def action
    # Within this scope only constants defined in `ABase` are resolved.
    # As ABase::C and ::C (root-level) don't exist, C can't be resolved.
    # However, a method `c` defined in a subclass will be.
    c.new.foo
  end
end

module M1
  class A < ABase
    def c
      C
    end
  end

  class C
    def foo
      puts "M1::C foo"
    end
  end
end

module M2
  class A < ABase
    # This resolves C as either M2::A::C, M2::ABase::C, M2::C or ::C,
    # whichever it finds first.
    def c
      C
    end
  end

  class C
    def foo
      puts "M2::C foo"
    end
  end
end
```

Then you get the expected results:

```
M1::A.new.action
# => M1::C foo
M2::A.new.action
# => M2::C foo
```

Comment: if there are many classes like C in M1 and M2 is there a way solve it without "aliasing" every class? An idea that comes to my mind is referencing the whole module somehow.

Comment: You can always reference `M2::C` anywhere you like, or maybe something like `constant_get(:C)` but you'd have to experiment. I've got a feeling this is more of an object-oriented design issue than a Ruby one: If you architect this differently the problem goes away.